# Show that $[\Bbb{Q}:\Bbb{Q}(\rho+i)]=8$ without using Primitive element theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

Let $\rho=p^{\frac{1}{4}}$ with $p$ prime. The proof that

$$\Bbb{Q}(\rho,i)=\Bbb{Q}(\rho+i)$$
follows directly from the Primitive element theorem. However, I'm curious if there is a explicit way of proving this by computing the minimal polynomial of $\rho+i$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ or at least show that

$$[\Bbb{Q}:\Bbb{Q}(\rho+i)]=8$$

since then by the transitivity property of the degree, we would get that

$$[\Bbb{Q}(\rho+i):\Bbb{Q}(\rho,i)]=1$$

and hence both extensions are equal.

I've tried it by brute force, that is letting $\alpha=\rho+i$ and squaring, substracting, etc to find a polynomial that has $\alpha$ as a root, but I always get things that are too messy to handle with degree $16$, so I'm need of new paths to solve the problem. My question the would be the following:

> Is there any simple way of showing that $$[\Bbb{Q}:\Bbb{Q}(\rho+i)]=8$$ without using then Primitive element theorem, that is, computing the minimal polynomial of $\rho+i$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ or using any other tool?

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Galois action on $\rho+i$ and seeing what elements fix it?

Comment: @Matt B Well, unfortunetly, that is something we haven't covered in class yet, so I don't really know what that is.

Comment: Apart from trying to brute force the minimal polynomial (since you know it must have degree 8), you could also try and write either $\rho$ or $i$ in terms of sums of powers of $\rho +i$ but this is laborious either. In short, I don't think there is another simple way without using some Galois theory.

Comment: I also want to add that for an extension $K(a,b)/K$, the primitive element theorem doesn't tell you that $K(a+b)=K(a,b)$, but merely that such an element $\alpha$ exists with $K(\alpha)=K(a,b)$, for example consider $\mathbb{Q}(i,-i)$.

Comment: @Matt B Yes, but in the proof of the primitive element theorem, we proved that $K(a,b)=K(a+\lambda b)$ for some $\lambda$, and this is just an especific case when $\lambda=1$ works.

Comment: @Matt B And well, if you'd like to answer the question using Galois theory, though at the moment I'd understand nothing, it might be useful for other people and even for me in a few weeks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, when I try to compute the minimal polynomial with $\alpha := \sqrt[4]{p} + \mathrm{i}$, I get:

\begin{align}
\alpha & = \sqrt[4]{p} + \mathrm{i} & \implies \\
(\alpha - \mathrm i )^4 &= p & \implies\\
(\alpha^2-2\alpha\mathrm i-1)^2 &= p & \implies \\
\alpha^4-6\alpha^2+1-p & = \mathrm i \cdot (4\alpha^3 - 4\alpha) & (\mathrm 1)
\end{align}

Square the last line, and (Wolfram Alpha is your friend) this leads to the polynomial

$$f(X) = X^8+4X^6+(6-2p)X^4+(4+12p)X^2+(p-1)^2$$

You can verify [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28p%5E%281%2F4%29%2Bi%29%5E8%2B4%28p%5E%281%2F4%29%2Bi%29%5E6%2B%286-2p%29%28p%5E%281%2F4%29%2Bi%29%5E4%2B%284%2B12p%29%28p%5E%281%2F4%29%2Bi%29%5E2%2Bp%5E2-2p%2B1), that $\sqrt[4]{p} + \mathrm i$ is a root of $f$.

Hmm, well now you could try to show that $f$ is irreducible. On a first glance this isn't obvious to me and may involve heroic computations.

You say that you know that $[\Bbb{Q}(\rho,\mathrm i):\Bbb{Q}] = 8$, so $[\Bbb{Q}(\rho+\mathrm i):\Bbb{Q}]$ divides 8 (so it's either 2,4 or 8). So another thing you could do now is show that it can't be 2 neither 4. In order to show that $[\Bbb{Q}(\rho+\mathrm i):\Bbb{Q}] \neq 2$, suppose it is. Then the minimal polynomial is of the form $X^2+aX+b \in \Bbb{Q}[X]$. Put in your $\alpha$ and get 
\begin{align}
a \sqrt[4]{p}+\mathrm i a+b+\sqrt[4]{p}+2 \mathrm i \sqrt[4]{p}-1 & = 0 \implies \\
a & = -2\sqrt[4]{p}\ \ \text{(because complex part of $b$ must be 0)}
\end{align}
, which cannot be. So $[\Bbb{Q}(\rho+\mathrm i):\Bbb{Q}] \neq 2$. In a similar way, you could show that it can't be 4 either. But I don't think this is any fun.

**On the other hand**, ($1$) shows at once what [Matt B](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/111938/matt-b) had been talking about in the comments: it shows that $\mathrm i = \displaystyle \frac{\alpha^4-6\alpha^2+1-p}{4\alpha^3-4\alpha} \implies \mathrm i \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \implies \mathbb{Q}(\rho, \mathrm i) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\rho + \mathrm i)$ and you're done.

PS: I'd rather write $[\Bbb{Q}(\rho+i):\Bbb{Q}]$ than $[\Bbb{Q}:\Bbb{Q}(\rho+i)]$ and put the bigger field on the left hand side of the ":".

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha= \rho+i$. Now $p=\rho^4= (\alpha-i)^4$, and the right hand side will be of the form $f(\alpha)+ i g(\alpha)$ for $f,g$ polynomials, and $g(\alpha)\neq 0$ since $\alpha^2-1\neq 0$ because $\rho^2 -1 \neq 0$ is its real part). This shows that $i$ lies in the subfield generated by $\alpha$. Thus $\rho$ does too, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer using a bit of Galois theory, as requested by @user314159. I realised whilst typing that this was a bit longer than expected, but there is a lot less guesswork and we never need to find the minimal polynomial.

First note $K=\mathbb{Q}(\rho,i)$ is the splitting field of the polynomial $f=x^4-p$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and hence is a Galois extension. We can directly determine that $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=8$ by the tower law since $f$ is irreducible and also has both real and complex roots.

This means that the Galois group $G=Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ has order $8$. Furthermore, we note that the subextension $\mathbb{Q}(\rho)/\mathbb{Q}$ is not Galois since $\rho$ has minimal polynomial $f$ and the splitting field of that is $K$. By the Galois correspondence theorem, $G$ must have a non-normal subgroup which means it must be isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_8$.

If we order the roots of $f$ to be $r_1=\rho, r_2=i\rho, r_3=-\rho, r_4=-i\rho$, then we can see that $G$ is generated by the elements $\sigma=(r_1,r_2)(r_3,r_4)$ and $\tau=(r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4)$.

Recall that $D_8$ has $10$ subgroups and so by the Galois correspondence theorem, if we can determine the number of elements of $G$ that fix $\rho+i$ (these form a subgroup), then we can find the degree of the extension.

Note that $5$ subgroups contain the element $\tau^2$ (this is the other element in the centre). Now $\rho+i=r_1+\frac{r_2}{r_1}$ so $\tau^2(\rho+i)=r_3+\frac{r_4}{r_3}=-\rho +i \neq \rho+i$. This means $\tau^2$ does not lie in the stabiliser subgroup and hence we've ruled out those $5$ options.

We are just left to check the elements $\sigma, \sigma\tau, \sigma\tau^2,\sigma\tau^3$ to rule out other subgroups with similar calculations. Having done this, we discover that the only element that fixes $\rho+i$ is the identity so the subgroup we're looking for has order $1$.

By the correspondence theorem again, this shows that $[\mathbb{Q}(\rho,i):\mathbb{Q}(\rho+i)]=1$ and so by the Tower Law, $[\mathbb{Q}(\rho+i):\mathbb{Q}]=8$ as required.